# Cumulative sum of multiple rasters in R

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have 200 rasters with air temperatures for each day stored in a directory and I would like to do a cumulative sum of temperatures for each day, e.g. 
day1 = day1; day2 = day1 + day2; day3 = day1 + day2 + day3, etc.
I tried to do it in `raster` package, but the `cumsum` function calculates the cumulative sum of all cells in each raster and not the cumulative sum of individual rasters (at least it seems to me from my results).
I tried to do it like this:

```
library(raster)

setwd("C:/Air_temperatures/AT") # set working directory

AT.files <- list.files(pattern="AT") # list files with name AT
All.AT <- unique(AT.files) # unique files
  for (i in 1:200) {
    AT.i <- All.AT[i] # make i
    AT.raster.i<-raster(AT.i) # make rasters from files
    AT.sum.i <- cumsum(AT.raster.i) # ???calculate cumulative sum???
    writeRaster(AT.sum.i,
               paste(AT.i, "_cumsum.tif", sep = ""),
              datatype='FLT4S', overwrite=TRUE) # write new files and paste new name
  }
```

This loop worked when I tried for example to add a constant to each raster and so on, but I have no idea how to calculate the cumulative sum.

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: I am not sure how. Once I provided a reproducible example but not with raster data. Each raster has approx. 4MB in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Reduce` function might help here. This function successively combines objects based on a specified function. Since there is a `+` method for `Raster*` objects, you can use this as the function and obtain a cumulative sum of the raster values.

First, create the 200 raster objects in a list:

```
theATs <- lapply(All.AT, raster)
```

Then, use the `Reduce` function with the `accumulate` argument set to `TRUE`

```
res <- Reduce("+", theATs, accumulate = TRUE)
```

Then write the results to files:

```
lapply(seq_along(res), function(x) {
    writeRaster(res[[x]],
# Apparently, using .tif files threw an error
#     paste(All.AT[x], "_cumsum.tif", sep = ""),
# Alternatively, omit file extension to write default type (usually .grd)
      paste(All.AT[x], "_cumsum", sep = ""),
      datatype = 'FLT4S', overwrite = TRUE)
    })
```

The rasters you create here are stored in memory, so if the original files are very large, you may run into problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answewr. But as you said, after some minutes of the calculation of the `reduce` function I am getting an error report: `cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Mb` Is any way how to fix this problem? I tried it on Windows XP Professional 32 bit with 4GB RAM.

Comment: OK, that's R saying it's run out of memory. With 32-bit Windows there's not much wiggle room, but you could see if increasing the limit using `memory.limit` helps. If that doesn't work, you could rewrite your loop to read in the previously saved raster (for `i > 1`), add the current raster values, and save the sum.

Comment: I tried it again on a Windows 7, 64 bit, 12 GB RAM and now the `reduce` function works, but after the `lapply` I am getting another error: `Error in .gd_SetProject(transient, projection(r)) : STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'logical' Called from: top level Browse[1]>` Have you any suggestions?

Comment: @user3624251, I've not seen that error, but there's a thread on the [r-sig-geo list](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Error-in-gd-SetProject-transient-crs-r-td7585330.html) that mentions the issue. If that doesn't help, I'm afraid I've reached my limits here.

Comment: Your approach is working, I just deleted `.tif` from the `cumsum.tif`. So now the new files are in the `.grd` format, but I can live with it. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into memory issues with the above, but try `sum(stack(theATs), filename="myoutput.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)` to write externally.